# How to create SSH Connection in Airflow from a variable

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to create a custom SSH connection via airflow since my hostname is dynamic I cant create directly under connections tab from airflow.

I have a function which returns the hostname. But how can I create the connection in airflow with the HOSTNAME returned from the function with username and Password which will be used for my ssh operator

```
 sshnodeDetails = data['ambariInfos']['hostComponents'][0]['hostName']
 if childProperty[0].text == 'hostName':
            childProperty[1].text = sshnodeDetails
logging.info("headNode detail is: " + sshnodeDetails)

Output: headNode detail is: hn0-rehXXX.azureprd.onmicrosoft.com

t1 = SSHOperator(
    ssh_conn_id='????',
    task_id='SparkSubmitCommand',
    command = sparkSubmitCommand,
    dag=dag)
```

Comment: `ssh_conn_id=sshnodeDetails` like that?

Comment: Yes, but how will i create connection from the variable it returned the host. I need to pass username and password as well to create connection id.